# NPM local dependency WITHOUT copying

Tags: npm

To make development easier it's possible to [specify local NPM dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "mylib": "file:/projects/mylib"
  }
}
```

The problem is that you required to do `npm install` and the `mylib` will be **COPIED** to the `node_modules`. So if you change `mylib` you need to run `npm install` again.

I wonder if there's a way to do the same but **as a link** not as a copy, so it will be the **live version** of the package and any change would be instantly visible?

Comment: On which operating system are you on? You might be able to create a temporary symlink for your use case.

Comment: [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) ?

Comment: @k0pernikus thanks, yea I was thinking about symlink although NPM keep erasing it, npm link yes probably the best way

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the npm link command, which works creating a symlink in the global npm folder, you can try using the [npm-file-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-file-link) package. It works modifying the original dependency by one to the local package using the "file:" npm feature, and you can link or unlink at a time all packages you want, whenever they are all under the same folder.