# Switch NodeJS module dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependencies

I am trying to build an SPA. I need to use some package lets call it package A. Package A has dependency on package B.
Now, I need to change something in package B. I made a fork of package B from GitHub. I also made a fork of package A. How do I tell package A to use my fork of package B? Package.json seems to have only name of the dependency without the source.
I searched online but all solutions talk about how to amend single node package and then do PR etc.

Thank you
Dan

UPD:
Setting package B as a dependency in package A in a format dependency:username/repo#branch-name
did not work.
It gives the error:
npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json. Package B fork definitely has package.json

Comment: Set in Package A, Package B as dependencie...

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer, [Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json/14387210#14387210) you could use a local dependency of package B that fork of package A points to.

Although hard to see, why!? if it's a code change can't be overridden or given an implementation in your own app code?

Comment: I am trying to make some changes to public package. Ultimately I would like to host the app in more environments other than local. Hence, I am trying to host updated package on github