# How can we build a node project in Jenkins while referencing another node project?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gitlab, continuous-integration, package.json

We've got an application (Angular/node in GitLab) that has a corresponding freestyle build in Jenkins.  In the package.json, we need to reference a separately-built library of our own writing, also in GitLab.  Like this:

```
"dependencies": {
     "our-library": "git+ssh://git@ourcompany.com:2222/libraries/our-library.git#master"
}
```

When we build the application in Jenkins, it pulls the source for our-library, which does not contain the generated lib files. The issue is that ideally we would not like to push the lib files generated by a local our-library build just so that the Jenkins build will be able to find what it needs for the application build. It's almost like we need to be able to reference the /lib folder in the Jenkins our-library workspace instead of referencing the source from GitLab, or something.

The fact that I need to ask this question gives me the feeling that we're going about this all wrong.  Any insight on how to build an app in Jenkins while referencing other node projects that we build as well?

Thanks a lot for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a source dependency, which means your Jenkins build needs to also build said dependencies (from its sources)

The other approach is binary dependency, where your `package.json` references a local dependency that you have copied (from a binary referential like Nexus, or from any other source you want, like a shared folder where you have put the generated libs).
See for instance "[Local dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387210/6309)".