# How does one import a third party library to an Angular project?

Tags: angular, dependencies, node-modules, package.json, tsconfig

I've got a project that needs to use a third-party custom library that was given for the project. How does one correctly use/integrate it? Do you have to import it to *"package.json"* like any other dependency?

```json
"dependencies": {
  "custom-lib": "^1.0.0",
  // other deps
}
```

When I try to do so, it kind of works but its assets do not load for example (404 (Not Found))...Does one need to add some references in *"angular.json"* too?
Describe the proper way of configuring this, please. Any advice is appreciated.

**Edit:**
Plus when running npm install, the library disappears from node_modules

Comment: Where is the library located? In node_modules? Did you install via npm or it just a folder?

Comment: @nullptr.t I moved it to the node_modules. It is just a custom library (a folder), not installable by npm.

Comment: Then you can reference it like this: `"custom-lib": "file:node_modules/custom-lib"` (I'm assuming the folder is named "custom-lib" as well)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json