# is it possible to automatically change the package.json when switch environment

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a public package, when I am developing in local machine, I want to use this package in local like this:

```
"rd-component": "file:../rd-component/rd-component-0.1.24.tgz",
```

using local package could make me change the pakcage more convenience. when I publish my project to porduction environmnet, I want to use this dependencies like this:

```
"rd-component": "0.1.24",
```

how to make the package.json automatically change like this? I have to edit the dependencies every time before I publish package to production environment right now. I have searching a component called [penv](https://github.com/julianduque/penv) but it stop update for years.

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json) which uses links for local development. That way your package.json can stay the same but reference different packages.