# Installing TextBelt on my own server

Tags: node.js, git, redis, npm

I want to install [TextBelt](https://github.com/typpo/textbelt), an open source cURL SMS API, to my own Amazon EC2 web server and use it to send text messages. However, I'm unsure about how to properly go about this.

I used `git` to clone all the files to a directory called `/var/www/textbelt`. I then used `npm` to install all of the dependencies listed in `package.json` file and created the symlink, as per the directions provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8374526/634324) answer. I saw that there's a bash script `start.sh` in the "scripts" folder, so i cd'ed into it and ran `sh start.sh`. I then got the following message:

```
nohup: appending output to ‘/home/ec2-user/nohup.out’
```

Naturally, I checked the log, and saw this:

```
^[[0;31mError: Cannot find module '/var/www/textbelt/scripts/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

For some reason `start.sh` references the `app.js` path incorrectly. I fixed this by changing `app.js` to `../app.js`, and tried again. This is my complete output:

```
^[[0;42m    hotnode ^[[m ^[[0;32mnode process restarted^[[m
^[[0;31mconnect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
^[[m
^[[0;31mvisit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
^[[m
^[[0;31mconnect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
^[[m
Listening on 9090
^[[0;31m
^[[m
^[[0;31mevents.js:72
^[[m
^[[0;31m        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m ^[[m
^[[0;31m^^[[m
^[[0;31m
^[[m
^[[0;31mError: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
    at RedisClient.on_error (/var/www/textbelt/node_modules/redis-url/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/textbelt/node_modules/redis-url/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
^[[m
```

After Googling "Redis connection to..failed", I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754304/redis-connection-to-127-0-0-16379-failed-connect-econnrefused) answer which suggested that the solution was to start the Redis server by typing `redis-server`. However, I get the following error:

```
-bash: redis-server: command not found
```

This suggests that redis was not installed properly. However, after looking at my `node_modules` folder, I see that there is indeed  a `redis-url` folder inside, which (I'm assuming) means that the dependency was properly installed? Do I have to do a server-wide install or something?

I'm kinda stuck here.

Overall, I am not sure if I am proceeding in the right direction. What is the proper way to install and start up the TextBelt API to get it running properly.

**Update:** Alright, so I figured out that I had to also install the `redis` server separately. Restarted everything, the logs look good now:

```
^[[0;42m    hotnode ^[[m ^[[0;32mnode process restarted^[[m
^[[0;31mconnect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
^[[m
^[[0;31mvisit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
^[[m
^[[0;31mconnect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
^[[m
Listening on 9090
```

However, I believe that further configuration is required to actually send a text message. For example, I tried using cURL to send a message using my server, just as I would to http://textbelt.com:

```
$ curl http://my.ip/text \ 
-d number=5551234567 \ 
-d "message=I sent this message for free with textbelt.com"
```

But this did not work (all I got was the HTML of my 404 not found page). One thing to note is that I currently have the `textbelt` folder in `/var/www/`, but the web document root is in `/var/www/html/`. I don't think that I have to actually move the folder to the document root, is this correct? How do I need to proceed?

Comment: You have to install [Redis](http://redis.io) server. What you have in your modules folder probably is some library/driver to talk with Redis

Comment: Salem, thanks! I actually just figured that out for myself. Updating my post now...

Comment: Salem, if you could maybe take a look at my updated post, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What about `http://my.ip:9090/text` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately the request just times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer was much simpler than I thought. There was nothing wrong with my installation, but port 9090 wasn't open in my firewall. Opening up this port fixed the problem immediately.